Looking for a service that maintains a database of global networking latencies
I was wondering if there is something like peeringdb.com that I can query about networking latencies between different internet locations.
Peeringdb.com just shows which connections a network has and it doesn't even let you query about paths between networks. Ideally I would be able to enter two network ASNs (or even IPs) and the service will produce latency results (historical or current) for the interconnect between these two networks.
